# Will a crimson chest spawn in a corruption world?

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I have a few of the legendry items from the dungeon chests now. I was wondering, if I managed to get a hold of a crimson key, would I be able to find a chest in my corruption world, or would I have to create a new crimson world and find it; is it already there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crimson chests are spawned during world generation, and only in worlds which have the Crimson. You will need to make a new world to find one.

Answer (score -4):

No, they will spawn in the Dungeon after you defeat Skeletron.